# Write DAX measure to check if selected value is in the list

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm attempting to conditionally format a Matrix based on a couple of columns. My matrix looks like so and it calculates worked hours per week.

| Employee | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 70 | 80 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 72 | 80 |
| C | 20 | 79 | 90 |

My source table I'm pulling from is the following:

| Employee | Week | Type | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Work | 70 |
| A | 2 | Work | 80 |
| B | 1 | PTO | 70 |
| B | 2 | Work | 72 |
| B | 3 | Work | 80 |
| C | 1 | Work | 20 |
| C | 1 | PTO | 50 |
| C | 2 | Work | 79 |
| C | 3 | Work | 90 |

I would like for the background to be red whenever the worked hours for a week fall below 70. However, I would like for the background to be yellow when the worked hours for a week fall below 70 BUT they have PTO hours within that same week.

My dax measure to conditionally format on the worked hours column looks like so:

```
Worked Hours by Pay Period Conditional Formatting =

Var Hours_Under_w_PTO = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Employeees'[Worked_Hours] < 70) && 
SELECTEDVALUE('Employees'[Type]) = "PTO", 1, 0)

Var Hours_Under = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Employees'[Worked_Hours] < 70, 1, 0)

RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    Hours_Under_w_PTO = 1, "Yellow",
    Hours_Under = 1, "Red"
    )
```

I'm able to get my desired output with Employee A on Week 3 to be RED and Employee B on Week 1 to be Yellow. However, I'm unable to get Employee C on Week 1 to be Yellow because there are multiple values, in this case 20 for work and 50 for PTO. I believe I need it to iterate through the multiple types and if one of them is PTO, then it should turn it to yellow.

How would I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You count the number of hours where type is PTO and if > 0 then you add that to you calculation:

```
Worked Hours by Pay Period Conditional Formatting =

Var Hours_PTO = CALCULATE(SUM'Employeees'[Worked_Hours], 'Employees'[Type] = "PTO")
Var Total_Hours = SUM('Employeees'[Worked_Hours])

RETURN IF(Total_Hours < 70, IF(Hours_PTO > 0, "Yellow", "Red"))
```